# Does friction depend on the direction of motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

In my experiment of finding the moment of inertia of a flywheel, I first rotate the flywheel in the anticlockwise direction and then in the clockwise direction, but I am getting different values of revolution. Does friction depend on the direction of rotation of the flywheel?

Comment: Are you asking whether, in the general case, flywheels are harder to rotate in one direction than the other?  If that's your question, then the answer is no.

Comment: @James, only for an idealized flywheel.

Comment: As a reminder: of course, friction in general depends of the direction of motion in the sense that it always *opposes* motion, its direction thus changes when you change motion direction. People below answer the question whether its magnitude should depend on the direction of motion.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, it depends  on the rubbing surfaces of the axle and the hole in the centre of the flywheel. They could have bumps and imperfections that are not symmetrical, so they act like ratchets, impeding movement more in one direction than the other.  Also, how can you be absolutely sure that you are producing equal rotational velocities in each direction?

Answer (score 2):

When talking theoretically, an ideal flywheel rotating clockwise or anticlockwise would face the same magnitude of frictional forces in opposite directions. But if the flywheel is made such so as to rotate in one direction only or has worn out and/or has been damaged might produce different magnitudes of frictional forces. The surfaces which is rotating on the axle might have quite significant number of unsymmetric irregularities on it as shown.

[image]